# How can I match similar strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I am working on a program and stuck on one part. My program accepts a user input of a string which also contains the '*' symbol. What I need to do is match this string with any of the resembling dictionary keys.

For Example:

```
dict = {'Mazda': [[2, 'brown', '2006']], 'Jaguar': [[1, 'black', '2020']],
 'Lamborghini': [[0, 'red', '2009']], 'Camaro SS': [[1, ''Matte Black', '1969']], 
'Dodge': [[1, 'grey', '2012']], "twin turbo'camaro": [[2, 'lime green', '2016']] }
```

If the user enters:

```
'*amaro'

or

'Cam*ro'

or 

'Camar*'
```

It will find all instances where there is 'Camaro' in the keys of the dictionary.

code so far...

```
name = input('Enter * for the missing letter ')
name = name.replace('*', '') # I was thinking if I took the hash out I can sort through they keys and find the most similar instances 
if name in dict.keys():
   nName = dict.get(name)
```

If the code worked the only output I need is proof of the two keys being found from the users input:

```
Camaro SS

twin turbo'camaro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modifying @mrzo's answer, you want to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) with case insensitive search (`re.search` instead of `re.match` because we are not looking for a complete key match):

```
name = input('Enter * for the missing letter ')

regex_name = name.replace('*', '.')

for car in cars:
    if re.search(regex_name, car, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(name, "matches", car)
```

where `cars` is your dictionary. Do not name as [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Using wildcard `.` is equivalent to any character in regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. `.` stands for a wildcard sign here

```
import re

cars = {
    'Mazda': [[2, 'brown', '2006']], 
    'Jaguar': [[1, 'black', '2020']],
    'Lamborghini': [[0, 'red', '2009']], 
    'Camaro SS': [[1, 'Matte Black', '1969']], 
    'Dodge': [[1, 'grey', '2012']], 
    "twin turbo'camaro": [[2, 'lime green', '2016']] 
}

name = input('Enter * for the missing letter ')

regex_name = name.replace('*', '.')

for car in cars:
    if re.match(regex_name, car):
        print(name, "matches", car)
```

Comment: Use `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

Comment: @Austin is there anywhere with complete documentation to regex for beginners?